# Sanitize passwords from system logs

Tags: security, logging, credentials, samba, cifs

Can passwords or other sensitive information be removed from system logs?

After mounting shares with

```
mount -t cifs -o username=[USER],password=[PASSWORD] //[HOST]/[SHARE] /[MOUNT_POINT]
```

checking logs with `journalctl` reveals that the command is recorded in its entirety, including the password.

Comment: I'm sure this is more a [Unix](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) question. I don't believe that `journalctl` allows for that - you may have to just use grep

Comment: @Horkrine Ah yes it would have been better to post in https://unix.stackexchange.com Is it possible (maybe for mods) to move this question there?